# Merging smaller pieces of source

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I'm an unsophisticated git user, managing changes to a novel manuscript (written in Markdown). Currently I have a first draft not under SCM, and a second draft that is in a git repository. I pull large sections of text from the first draft file into the second draft, revise/rewrite, and commit the newest version of the second draft. I'm actually planning on finding a way to bring the first draft in as a new origin and making my second draft a branch, but that's another topic.

I'm also taking a writing class, and need to take small portions of text from the second draft and present them to my instructor. He returns them to me with revision advice. How can I most effectively use git to (a) pull out these subsets of the text from the repository into a branch of their own and (b) merge them back in after making changes. Currently I know how to do this with a single file, but am not sure how to bring this smaller revised piece back into the main branch. (I primarily use Sourcetree to manage things, but am not afraid of the git command line).